# Desktop does not power on, replacing power supply and mother board did not change anything

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop

We fried a desktop PC when trying to connect the power supply to a PCI device using a makeshift cable (please don't judge me) because the the power supply didn't have enough pins. Apperently we did something wrong and ever since the PC does not power up anymore. Of course we removed the PCI device but it did not help.
We replaced the power supply (Corsair CX450M) and the motherboard (B350 PC Mate)  while still using the old CPU (AMD Ryzen), GPU, RAM and harddrive but it did not change anything. I also removed and reattached all cables. There is still no lifesign from the PC. When we press the power button just nothing happens, no LEDs or fans turn on. The only thing is when I plug the power cable into the power supply I can hear a    high-pitched buzzing sound from the motherboard.
What else could be broken to explain this behaviour? E.g. if the CPU is fried, shouldn't the PC at least power on a bit before it notices that?

Comment: Have you got a backup of the data? If not, you should consider mounting the drive in another machine and getting a copy.

Comment: Do you get any kind reaction if you remove every device (maybe with the exception of the CPU)?

Comment: Fortunately we got a backup of the data before so that's not an issue at all.
@Seth: I did as you said and removed everything: GPU, WiFi card, RAM and all cables which go from the mainboard to the front connectors and the hard drive. So the only things left are the cables between the power supply and mainboard/CPU and to the power button and LEDs at the front. Still no lifesign. Is it possible that the PC does not even power on a bit if only the CPU is broken? Because that's the only thing left in my opinion.